# Visual Studio 2015 Project no .vs folder?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, applicationhost

I've migrated a visual studio 2010 project to visual studio 2015. I build the project in VS2015 and everything builds fine but I don't see any `.vs` folder in the solution which normally contains the following file:

```
$(solutionDir)\.vs\config\applicationhost.config
```

How do I generate this folder and the `applicationhost.config` file?

Comment: I believe it will use the existing legacy `applicationHost.config` file in your `C:\Users\$me\AppData\Local\Temp\iisexpress\config` or `C:\Users\$me\Documents\IISExpress\config` directories.

Comment: Try deleting your `.suo` and `.csproj.user` files (which contain some IIS configuration settings) and removing all IIS + ASP.NET MSBuild properties from your `.csproj` file (like `<ISExpressClassicPipelineMode>`, restarting VS, then configuring Web settings in the Project Properties window.

Comment: @Dai ok i've found it but non of the CSS is loading in browser. I have Anon Auth disabled and Win Auth enabled?